Configure Json Scheme to support mixed objects in array
I’m trying to get my schema to accept two different objects within my response.
This is example JSON I’d like to get:
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "title": "Lolipop",
      "type": "candy"
    },
    {
      "title": "Apples",
      "type": "fruit",
      "taste": "sweet",
      "cal": 1000
    },
    {
      "title": "Cucumber",
      "type": "vegetable",
      "taste": "regular",
      "cal": 200
    }
  ]
}

And here is my current scheme:
   let jsonSchema: [String: Any] = [
        "type": "json_schema",
        "json_schema": [
            "name": "groceries_schema", // Name of the schema
            "schema": [
                "type": "object",
                "properties": [
                    "tasks": [
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": [
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": [
                                "title": ["type": "string"],
                                "type": [
                                    "type": "string",
                                    "enum": ["vegetable", "fruit", "candy"] // Define enum values for type
                                ],
                                "taste": [
                                    "type": ["string", "null"] // Allow date to be null if not provided
                                ],
                                "cal": [
                                    "type": ["string", "null"] // Allow time to be null if not provided
                                ]
                            ],
                            "required": ["title", "type", "cal", "taste"], // Include all properties in required
                            "additionalProperties": false
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                "required": ["tasks"], // Require the "tasks" array
                "additionalProperties": false
            ],
            "strict": true // Enable strict mode
        ]
    ]

This makes the GPT to responsd with “cal”: null and “taste”: null for objects that should use the simplified object, I’m trying to get results without those null values.
I’d love some help here, thank you!
